# VHDL Don't Care for custom type

Tags: vhdl

So I was working on a simple computer in VHDL and I created my ALU using a custom type for the control signal to give the synthesizer freedom to choose a specific encoding scheme which simplifies the ALU logic.  Great.

I then went to write the control unit, and for some operations the ALU is not being used.  Ideally, for those cycles I would specify a Don't Care condition for the ALU control signals to avoid potentially requiring a bunch of extra logic to force it to one specific state which I might choose poorly.  However, I can't find anything about how or if its even possible to specify a don't care condition for a signal of a custom type.  Replacing the alu_op signal with a std_logic_vector fixes the control unit problem, but then requires me to manually specify the encodings in the ALU.  Is there any way I can get the best of both worlds (allow the synthesizer to choose the ALU encoding, and also generate logic with Don't Care in the control unit)?

My custom type is defined in a package file as

```
type ALU_op is (PASS_A, PASS_B, ADD, SUB);
```

Then the ALU looks like:

```
entity ALU is 
    GENERIC(N : integer := 8);
    PORT(
        A, B : IN unsigned(N-1 downto 0);
        OP : IN ALU_op;
        R : OUT unsigned(N-1 downto 0)
    );
end ALU;

architecture arch of ALU is
    signal result : unsigned(N-1 downto 0);
begin
    with OP select
    R <= 
        A when PASS_A,
        B when PASS_B,
        A+B when ADD,
        A-B when SUB;
end arch;
```

And then in the control unit (among other things) I wan't to do something like:

```
process(state)
begin
    case state is
        when S1 => alu_op <= PASS_A;
        when S2 => alu_op <= ADD;
        when S3 => alu_op <= ???; --Don't Care, currently have to pick an arbitrary value
        ... (etc)
    end case;
end process;
```

I realize for this small example it won't make much of a difference but it seemed like something that should be possible and could be very beneficial in a more complex system.  Thanks!

Comment: apart from adding a don't care in your type, that will be merged to the operation you'll do in the ALU, I don't see any way to do that... By the way, you should always have a when others, whatever the type used.

Comment: First you need to ask, is there really an issue?   So synthesize the design with the enumerated types (just the 4 you currently have) and one with std_logic_vector and don't cares.    Are they different in size?   Does any difference gain you anything - such as you can run the design faster?  Is either coding style more maintainable?  It is unlikely that you can reduce the size of the ALU - OTOH, if you add an extra enum value, you may increase the size.   An effective X mapping may save little logic in the generation of PASS_A, PASS_B, ..., but then again, you may not.

Comment: @B.Go I would not always recommend using others. When using with select or case statement, all cases MUST be covered. For a custom type, using others may cover the fact you have forgotten about some of the options. So being explicit and not including a when others case means the compiler will pick up something you forgot.